# tmux: pane make up windows, windows make up sessions. Now whats the use of session groups?

Tags: tmux

panes make up windows. A session can have multiple windows. But what is the use case of session groups?
Is it a group of sessions?

Answer (score 0):

The name 'session group' is very confusing. It sounds like it is a group of multiple sessions (pane(s) -> window(s) -> session -> session group). Wrong.

Its actually pane(s) -> window(s) ->  (optional) session group -> session

Session group acts a a view of a session. Without session group every user connected will have the same view. If one user changes to another window - all users connected to the same session will change to that window.

But it can be useful to use session only to have access to all the windows, but let users independently decide which window to use at the moment. So that bob can use window1, and alice window2.

Note that bob can change to window2 if he decides to. And then both will see each other typing.

Perhaps a more appropriate name for 'session group' would be a 'session view'.